# How to multiply objects of different template type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

How can I make it so that (with objects of different template types) A*B and B*A give the same result, **where the type of the result is determined according to the usual C++ type promotion rules**?

For example:

```
int main()
{
    number<float> A(2.0f);    
    number<double> B(3.0);
    A*B; // I want 6.0 (double)
    B*A; // I want 6.0 (double)

    return 0;
}
```

At the moment, I can only multiply objects of the same template type. For example, something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class number
{
    public:

        number(T v) : _value(v) {}

        T get_value() const { return _value; }

        number& operator*=(const number& rhs)
        {
            _value *= rhs.get_value(); 
            return *this;
        } 

    private:

        T _value;
};

template<typename T>
inline number<T> operator*(number<T> lhs, const number<T>& rhs)
{
  lhs *= rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

EDIT: Or, as in the answers, I can multiply objects of different template types, but **always returning the same type as lhs**. Is there any way to instead return an object whose type is determined by the standard type promotion rules?

EDIT 2: <s>I would like to avoid C++11 features if possible</s>.

Comment: why do you want to avoid c++11 features?

Comment: Because I'm not sure if any/some/all of the toolchains I use in various places can build C++11 code and I don't know how painful it is to make the transition. If C++11 is necessary, then I will start downloading upgrades so I can get this sorted.

Comment: It's easy with C++11 (see my answer), but I don't know about a solution with C++03 (and honestly see no point in seeking one).

Comment: What compilers do you use? Clang,GCC, Intel compiler,  VisualStudio and XCode (based on clang) have supported C++11 for years (VS support is not complet, but complete enough for the problem at hand). Also the default compiler (gcc) on almost any still supported linux distribution should support the necessary subset of c++11 features. But even if one of your compilers doesn't  support it, I'd assume it is less pain to go through the update process once than having to stick to pre c++11 code.

Comment: I mostly use GCC, but occasionally have to use Visual Studio. I have sorted out this laptop (which was painless) and will deal with other computers as I use them. Both the answers work really nicely, but at the moment I am using `common_type`, as it seems marginally more direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::common_type<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) to obtain the type required for the return. For example

```
template<typename X>
struct number
{
  // ...

  template<typename Y>
  number(number<Y> const&other);              // needed in line 1 below

  template<typename Y>
  number&operator=(number<Y> const&other);    // you may also want this

  template<typename Y>
  number&operator*=(number<Y> const&other);   // needed in line 2 below

  template<typename Y>
  number<typename std::common_type<X,Y>::type> operator*(number<Y> const&y) const
  {
    number<typename std::common_type<X,Y>::type> result=x;   // 1
    return result*=y;                                        // 2
  }
};
```

I left out the implementations of the templated constructor and `operator*=`.

---

Unfortunately, `std::common_type` is C++11, which you want to avoid for obscure reasons. If you only work with built-in types (`double`, `float`, `int`, etc), you can easily implement your own version of `common_type`. However, if you want to do sophisticated meta-template programming, it is strongly recommended to move on to C++11 – it's already 4 years old and mostly backwards compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will run some upgrades and have a look at this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to templatize e.g. the `rhs`parameters:

```
template<typename T>
class number
{
public:

    number(T v) : _value(v) {}

    T get_value() const { return _value; }
    template<class E>
    number& operator*=(const number<E>& rhs)
    {
        _value *= rhs.get_value(); 
        return *this;
    } 

private:

    T _value;
};

template<class T, class E, class RET = decltype(T()*E())>
number<RET> operator*(number<T>& lhs, const number<E>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.get_value()*rhs.get_value();
}
```

Comment: @Harry: I changed `operator*` to a version, that will always return the proper type.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising. I will run some upgrades and then give this a try.

Comment: That seems to work, but I don't actually understand how it compiles. I feel like it should `return number<RET>(lhs.get_value()*rhs.get_value());` ... In your version I don't understand how it converts to `number<RET>`.

Comment: @Harry: As the constructor of `number` is not `explicit`, the result of the multiplication is implicitly converted to the output data type, but of course you can also make the conversion explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You need a templated overload for the `operator*()`

```
template<typename T>
class number {
    public:
    // ...
    template<typename U>
    number& operator*=(const number<U>& rhs) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
 };
```

And the same for the binary operator

```
template<typename T,typename U>
inline number<T> operator*(number<T> lhs, const number<U>& rhs) {
  lhs *= rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

Comment: That alone will not be enough, you also have to introduce a second template parameter for the overloaded `*`-operator

Comment: @MikeMB That's exactly what I'm proposing?

Comment: No only the unary  `number& operator*=(const number<U>& rhs)` but also the binary `number<T> operator*(number<T> lhs, const number<T>& rhs)`

Comment: But this always returns type T and never type U. The part I'm really interested in is how to get the return type right. For example, I want 2.0f * 3.0 == 3.0 * 2.0f == 2.0 * 3.0f == 3.0f * 2.0 == 6.0 (double). Is this possible?

Comment: If you want `U` returned, just switch it in the return type declaration?

Comment: But then it always returns type U and never type T, right?

Comment: @Harry You also may use `auto`.

Comment: Is auto since C++11? I don't think I can use C++11... I will add this condition to the question.

Comment: @Harry Yes. It's since C++11. Well otherwise you'll have to pick one of those types.